# Bring FMIT (Free Music INstrument Tuner) into Eclipse as a project, Build and Run in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu

I am trying to import the download available at http://home.gna.org/fmit/ into Eclipse  (on Ubuntu), compile and run.

I have managed to create a C++ project in Eclipse, and then use the project wizard to import the home folder of the FMIT download. But I am lost when it comes to using the makefile to set the project up, build and run it.

I do .net VB website and Database development so I am kind of lost in Eclipse.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

FMIT exists in Ubuntu's repository. Is there any reason why you can't just use Ubuntu's version, or do you specifically need to compile from source?

```
sudo apt-get install fmit
```